# How can I create an XML feed from Google Sheets?

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to **create an XML feed from a Google Sheet**, to use in other applications. I want this feed to *update whenever changes are made* to the sheet. I checked out the Sheets API but couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Apps Script and use the Apps script services which include [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service) and [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).

Use [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) like [`onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to execute some code when someone makes changes to the linked Spreadsheet.

If you need to make a POST request you can use the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch).

As you can see Apps Script is a great tool for extending G Suite and more.

---

### Further reading:

- [Apps Script Quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/fundamentals-codelabs#getting_started)